Accessing relationship fields for setting and filtering using fflib
We are starting to use fflib in our projects. We generally run into disagreements on how we access relationship fields and as well copy values from related fields and set a object field. To set a field usually the approach promoted in the discussion boards of fflib repo recommend using map<id, string> for each field to set field values in the object. In our use cases where need to basically copy the discount details (close to 6 fields) and stamp it on 6 fields in the quotelineitem upon creation and if the discount only for a specific sku's family and if the opportunity is of "end customer" record type, then it requires quite bit of extra queries and code to get the job done.
If I need to do above, i will have to do something like this:
  IQuoteLines quotelines = IQuoteLines.newInstance(this.records);

  IQuotes quotes = IQuotes.newInstance(
      IQuotesSelector.newInstance().selectById(
        quotelines.getQuoteIds()
      )
  );   
  
  List<String> recordtypeids = Process_Constant__mdt.getInstance('Discount_Enabled_Opp_RecordType')
  .Value__c.split(',');

  Set<Id> opportunityIds = quotes.getOpportunityIds();
  
  IOpportunities opps = IOpportunities.newInstance(
    IOpportunitiesSelector.newInstance().getRecordIds(opportunityIds)
  ).selectByRecordTypeId(recordtypeids);

  IQuotes endcustomerQuotes = quotes.selectByOpportunityId(opps.getRecordIds());
  
  quotelines.selectByQuoteId(endcustomerQuotes.getRecordIds());
  
  //let us say we have discounts now
  IDiscounts dicounts = IDiscounts.newInstance(<list>)
  
  quotelines.
      setDistiMargin(Map<Id, Decimal>) // Map<ProductId, DistiMargin>
      setDistiDiscount(Map<Id, Decimal>) //
      setResellerMargin(Map<Id, Decimal>) //
      .....
   Instead of above, 
   quotelines.
     setDistiMargin(Map<Product2Id, IDiscounts>)
     //=> should this set call IDiscounts.getDistiMargin(), 
     //setDistiDiscount() within Quotelines Domain class?


Is there easy way to pass quote discount domains around and set the fields on the quoteline?
Even for the filtering the opps and quoteline's sku. I have to get quotes, then get opps and filter it. Same for sku's family, get productids and filter by family : This seems like we need additional queries and writing lot of code to a simple filter using relationship filed. Is there an acceptable way to address this concern?


I don't understand how this question has anything to do with fflib.  fflib selectors can return parent objects and child objects just like any normal soql.  Is your question on how to write a selector that return parents and children?

@cropredy My question is around how can we get the field values from relationship field without needing to querying the independently using their selector and access multiple fields without having to create maps for each field.
